# How do I search through a python list for a search term?

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have no idea what to do for this question.I have tried:
`mySearchterm in myQuestionlist`
as code.
In this 'mySearchterm' is the search term and 'myQuestionlist' is the list I am searching through for the search term.
`myQuestionlist = [a,b,c,d]`

Comment: Provide the list you're looking through as well as the value you are searching for and the code for how you've attempted to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still check if something is in your list but you have to be sure that they are the same type (Ex: If you search for the integer 1 in a list looking like ['1', '2', '3'] it will give you False)
Also , if you don't/can't use that method you can just loop over the list like:

```
for item in myQuestionlist:
    if item == mySearchterm:
        #Do something
```